# Creating custom message types in win32?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

Is there a way to define and send custom message types in Win32, to be caught by your Main message handler? For example, my main message handler captures messages such as WM_PAINT, WM_RESIZE, WM_LBUTTONDOWN etc. Can I create my own WM_DOSOMETHING? If so, how would I send this message?

Ah, I actually just discovered this was asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293723/how-could-i-create-a-custom-windows-message), however, it doesn't answer how I would actually send this message.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes.  Just declare a constant in the WM_USER range e.g.

```
#define WM_RETICULATE_SPLINES (WM_USER + 0x0001)
```

You can also register a message by name using the RegisterWindowMessage API.

You can then send these messages using SendMessage, PostMessage or any of their variants.

Comment: thanks! Is it necessary to RegisterWindowMessage() if the message is being sent and captured within one application only?

Comment: If using #define, be sure to use parentheses around (WM_USER + 0x0001) so arithmetic performed on your new message number (bitwise operations, packing into a high-order word, etc.) works correctly.

Comment: And no, you don't need RegisterWindowMessage if there's only one application involved; only if you need two apps to agree on a single message number.

Comment: It can be wise.  WM_USER messages are private to a window class, not an application.  So if your main window class defines WM_RETICULATE_SPLINES to be WM_USER + 0x0001, then send that message to a MyThirdPartyControl, the MyThirdPartyControl is at liberty to interpret that as WM_SEND_RUDE_EMAIL_TO_BOSS_THEN_FORMAT_C.  So use WM_USER only for communication within a window class, or when you're sure you know which class of window you're posting to.  Otherwise, RWM is safer.  See the RWM docs for more info.

Comment: see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644931%28VS.85%29.aspx for a description of the message number ranges; depending on your problem, `WM_APP` might be a better fit than `WM_USER`

Comment: Or better declare it as `const DWORD WM_RETICULATE_SPLINES = (WM_USER + 0x0001);`

Comment: +1 "Reticulating Splines" heh.  Haven't played that game in years, but it's a winner.

Answer (score 19):

Woah, let's just stop and think here...

First of all, Windows itself sends messages in the `WM_USER+n` range, that's why `WM_APP` was invented (I found this out the hard way). But it gets worse... there's nothing to stop badly behaved applications **broadcasting** `WM_USER+n` or `WM_APP+n` messages, and because human beings stole the crystal of infinite stupidity from the Gods, this does indeed happen in the real world.

So, repeat after me, the only safe message is one I define myself and can only see myself. Use RegisterWindowMessage. And even then, be untrusting. When I need a string to define a RegisterWindowMessage, I use GUIDGEN to create the string and put a human-readable app-specific prefix on the resulting gobbledygook to help me differentiate multiple messages in the code.

Bet on the stupidity of your fellow humans - it's always a winning bet.

If you want authoritative background on this whole topic, see [here](http://www.flounder.com/messages.htm). No that's not my website, it's Joe Newcomer's.

Comment: "because human beings stole the crystal of infinite stupidity from the Gods"  Better stupid humans than stupid Gods, though ;)

Answer (score 2):

- If you created the window **class**, you can use the `WM_USER` range (or `WM_APP`)
- If it is not your class, you can use `WM_APP`
- If you want to broadcast the message to every top level window, register your own global message with RegisterWindowMessage