# console out in multi-threaded applications

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, logging

Usually developing applications I am used to print to console in order to get useful debugging/tracing information. The application I am working now since it is multi-threaded sometimes I see my `printf` overlapping each other.

I tried to synchronize the screen using a `mutex` but I end up in slowing and blocking the app. How to solve this issue?

I am aware of MT logging libraries but in using them, since I log too much, I slow ( a bit ) my app.

I was thinking to the following idea..instead of logging **within** my applications why not log **outside** it? I would like to send logging information via socket to a second application process that actually print out on the screen.

Are you aware of any library already doing this?
I use Linux/gcc.

thanks

afg

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have 3 options.  In increasing order of complexity:

1. Just use a simple mutex within each thread.  The mutex is shared by all threads.
2. Send all the output to a single thread that does nothing but the logging.
3. Send all the output to a separate logging application.

Under most circumstances, I would go with #2.  #1 is fine as a starting point, but in all but the most trivial applications you can run in to problems serializing the application.  #2 is still very simple, and simple is a good thing, but it is also quite scalable.  You still end up doing the processing in the main application, but for the vast majority of applications you gain nothing by spinning this off to it's own, dedicated application.

Number 3 is what you're going to do in preformance-critical server type applications, but the minimal performance gain you get with this approach is 1:  very difficult to achieve, 2: very easy to screw up, and 3:  not the only or even most compelling reason people generally take this approach.  Rather, people typically take this approach when they need the logging service to be seperated from the applications using it.

Comment: 3 is also used when someone doesn't feel like reinventing the syslog/syslog-ng/msyslog/rsyslog wheel yet another time.

Answer (score 1):

As I know critical section has less weight.

- [Critical section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Using critical section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686908%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

If you use gcc, you could use atomic accesses. [Link.](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html)

Comment: The asker of the question is already using a mutex, and if he's on Windows, that itself already uses Critical sections, at least that's how I've seen them implemented; so doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @leetNightshade: I haven't seen the source code of MS Windows, but MSDN says in the linked document: _A critical section object provides synchronization similar to that provided by a mutex object, except that a critical section can be used only by the threads of a single process. Event, mutex, and semaphore objects can also be used in a single-process application, but critical section objects provide a slightly faster, more efficient mechanism for mutual-exclusion synchronization (a processor-specific test and set instruction)._

Comment: Ohh okay.  Well, when I did my research in the past all my sources say to create your own mutex like this: [link](http://leetnightshade.com/archives/231)  Which happen to use just that.  I've never seen anyone do different.

Comment: @leetNightshade: It is commonly used in Windows only sources.

Comment: @Naszta And that block is technically correct, because even if a mutex uses critical sections, the constructor and function calls to the mutex do make it a littler slower to use. lol.

Comment: @Naszta The game engine I'm writing has an IMutex class, so I can plugin whatever type of mutex I want on a per platform basis.  So, not exactly; technically it is as far as only being usable in Windows, but the idea isn't limited to just that; I could use atomics inside of a Mutex class for Linux.

Comment: @leetNightshade: anyway: if the log eats the most of the CPU time, something is not okay in the code.

Comment: @Naszta It's not eating most of the CPU time, it's just stalling his program because of the constant Mutex locking up print calls, which themselves take long. Heck, we're just talking about console prints, writing to a log would take even longer wouldn't it?

Comment: @Naszta logging to the console 'can' be slower than logging to a file, since every line has to typically, be displayed on the screen through the relevant window.  Most windowed console outputs aren't really that fast (because they're not expecting that much output to be rammed through them).

Comment: @leetNightshade: if the log take longer time than file prints, separate log process is preferred. If the host process crash, the log process has got time to finish the logging from the memory.

Comment: For having a separate process to actually make a difference to what's logged, each log call in the program is going to have to block, waiting for the remote process to add the item to it's queue (assuming a shared memory implementation isn't used).  This may be a not insignificant wait, particularly if for example communication has to be reestablished.  In the event of an actual crash, you're often going to be better off looking in the core file, the logs are only going to give a hint as to what was going on.

Comment: @leet:  A `CRITICAL_SECTION` is a completely different animal from a Mutex.  They have similar semantics, but they are not the same.  CS's are a user-mode device and, cannot be shared across processes.  Mutexes are a kernel device, and therefore a context switch is required to synchronize on them.  The lack of context switch in a critical section is why the crit sec is faster.

Comment: @John  Wait, so can a Mutex can be used across processes?

Comment: @leet:  Of course.  Just give it a name.  That is the purpose of the name parameter when calling `CreateMutex(...)`

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in the above comment which I'm sure made things *very* confusing.  It's fixed now.

Comment: @John Ohh okay, that makes sense now, thanks.  Yeah, frankly from all the Windows samples I've seen, I never realized that function or windows Mutexes even existed, I've been rolling my own as that's what I've seen others do. So thank you, you guys have been most informative.

Answer (score 1):

Which OS are you using?

Not sure about specific library's, but one of the classical approaches to this sort of problem is to use a logging queue, which is worked by a writer thread, who's job is purely to write the log file.

You need to be aware, either with a threaded approach, or a multi-process approach that the write queue may back up, meaning it needs to be managed, either by discarding entries or by slowing down your application (which is obviously easier if it's the threaded approach).

It's also common to have some way of categorising your logging output, so that you can have one section of your code logging at a high level, whilst another section of your code logs at a much lower level.  This makes it much easier to manage the amount of output that's being written to files and offers you the option of releasing the code with the logging in it, but turned off so that it can be used for fault diagnosis when installed.

Comment: Hi. I am using Linux and gcc. I see your point. I think that with a lock free queue this can be done, but the main part ( as noted by responses below ) will be a bit of work in coordinating the entries enqueued in case of multiple queues..here I see a lot of ideas coming out.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, a Mutex is the only way you really want to do that, so it's always going to be slow in your case because you're using so many print statements.... so to solve your question then, don't use so many print_f statements; that's your problem to begin with.

Okay, is your solution using a mutex to print? Perhaps you should have a mutex to a message queue which another thread is processing to print; that has a potential hang up, but I think will be faster. So, use an active logging thread that spins waiting for incoming messages to print.  The networking solution could work too, but that requires more work; try this first.

Comment: If you send dynamically-allocated strings or data to a worker thread in the form of some kind of job, you can avoid all locks.

Comment: @John Yes, but a lock/mutex is needed for the message queue itself inside of the worker thread, is it not?

Comment: Not if there is only one worker thread.  This can be done with no locks anywhere, even if `n` threads are sending output.

Comment: @John Let's say the worker thread is using a vector, and you have two threads trying to add elements by calling this function which adds the elements.  I thought you'd have a dead lock since the two threads are trying to expand and insert elements at the same time.

Comment: @leet:  The two threads don't access the vector directly.  Only the worker thread uses the vector.  Instead, the two threads instantiate jobs and send those jobs to the worker thread; not via a queue or shared data structure, but via some kind of messaging system.  That's what I meant by "some kind of job."  See this link for two ways to accomplish this under Windows:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783713/c-win32-executing-a-method-on-ui-thread-due-to-an-event-on-background-thread/3783845#3783845

Comment: @John Let's say for example:
WorkerThread.PostMessage("Message");

While this belongs to the worker thread, it can be called by any thread, and can thus can be called at the same time.  And in an implementation that I'm aware of, this PostMessage function would add the message to the message queue or whatever; and as a result, as far as I thought, provide issues while expanding the queue because of concurrency.  

I'm attempting to write a cross-platform engine, so would love it if you could explain to me a messaging system that doesn't work on a platform specific basis.

Comment: @John I would rather not have to rely on the OS's messaging system when I could write my own that would work on a cross-platform basis.  Unless you think it's absolutely necessary to abstract out a system to work around the platform's messaging system; however, can you say for a fact all platforms have such a feature? What about consoles, or portables like the DS? So, as far as I know, I need to create my own messaging system, and can't rely on the Windows one. So from that pov, I think the original issue still stands at having to use a mutex/cs when expanding your message queue.

Comment: I can't tell you about a cross-platform method because I don't know one.  But I can tell you that it is the operating system that typically manages this messaging queue, not the programmer.

Comment: Sure, if the hardware you're working on doesn't support a multiprocess mesasging queue, you're going to have to write your own.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to have one queue per thread, and have the logging thread routinely go through each of these and post the message somewhere.

This is fairly easy to set up and the amount of contention can be very low (just a pointer swap or two, which can be done w/o locking anything).

Comment: Hi Macke! It sounds good to me 'cos w/o locking I would expect low impact on application performance. I was probably thinking that going routinely from one queue to another might not respect the order, but If I timestamp or put a sequence number implemented as aotmic vairble( no lock ) it should work. Thanks a lot for the suggestion!