# Please help me check the code about Databinding in Silverlight for Windows Embedded

Tags: c++, multithreading, silverlight, data-binding, windows-embedded

I'm sorry to cause you a lot of trouble to read my question, because I'm a Chinese ,my English is poor, but the question has been bothering me a long time.

When I build a test-codes about Databinding,then meet a trouble.

I creat a second thread which has a cycle to generate data-source , then the thread call a method in MainPage to populate ListBoxItem.

The method use two way to do this. One use Databinding and another use ListBoxItem's SetContent().

the result is that the Databinding run about dozens of cycles then stop,but the SetContent() can run to finish.

Following is my whole codes based Windows Embedded Silverlight Tools, and run in CEPC

MainPage.XAML

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"

xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

x:Class="test6.MainPage"

Width="640" Height="480">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">

    <Button x:Name="Button1" Height="43" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,111,83,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="117" Content="Button"/>

    <ListBoxItem x:Name="ListBoxItem1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="84,111,0,0" Width="138" Content="{Binding L1}" Height="52" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#CEFFA3A3" FontSize="16"/>

    <ListBoxItem x:Name="ListBoxItem2" Height="43" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="84,187,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="138" Content="{Binding L2}" Background="#6971FF6E" FontSize="16"/>

</Grid>
```

First add

```
pWindowParameters->AllowsMultipleThreadAccess = true;
```

in App::GetWindowParameters , if not , SetContent() could appear like DataBinding.

Declare in MainPage.h

```
HRESULT MainPage::UpdateData();
```

and

```
DWORD WINAPI Thread2 (PVOID pArg);
```

DataValue.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <oleauto.h>

#include "XRCollection.h"

#include "XRPropertyBag.h"

class _declspec(uuid("{9C0158BE-D467-4284-A51A-327DEFE935C5}")) DataValue : public TPropertyBag<DataValue>

{

protected:

    // Protected, create by using TPropertyBag::CreateInstance to create an instance, then call Initialize();

    // this will CreateInstance will use XRObject to implement IUnknown, which saves us work.

    DataValue() {};

public:

    HRESULT Initialize(float l1,float l2)

    {

        HRESULT hr = InitializeProperties();

        m_L1 =l1;

        m_L2 =l2;

        return hr;

    }

     TBoundProperty<float> m_L1;

     TBoundProperty<float> m_L2;

    // Mapping TBoundProperty and property names.

    HRESULT InitializeProperties()

    {

        HRESULT hr = S_OK;

        hr = BeginRegisterProperties();

        if (FAILED(hr))

            return hr;   

        hr = RegisterBoundProperty(L"L1", m_L1);

        if (FAILED(hr))

            return hr;

        hr = RegisterBoundProperty(L"L2", m_L2);

        if (FAILED(hr))

            return hr;

        hr = EndRegisterProperties();

        return hr;

    }

};
```

In MainPange.cpp:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "test6Generated.h"

#include "MainPage.h"

#include "App.h"

#include "resource.h"

#include "DataValue.h"

#include "oleauto.h"

#include "XRPropertyBag.h"

static XRPtr<DataValue> pDataValue;

static XRValue xrvalueNew;

static float i=0;

// ============================================================================

//  OnLoaded

//

//  Description: Calls InitializeComponent to bind member variables to named

//               elements, and attach event handlers specified in XAML

//

//  Parameters:  pRoot - The root dependency object.

// ============================================================================

HRESULT MainPage::OnLoaded(__in IXRDependencyObject* pRoot)

{

    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(pRoot);

    HRESULT hr = InitializeComponent();

    // Add calls to FindName or Add___EventHandler() methods after this comment.

    DataValue::CreateInstance(&pDataValue);

    pDataValue->Initialize(1,2);

    XRValue DataContext(pDataValue);

    m_pListBoxItem1->SetDataContext(&DataContext);

    //m_pListBoxItem2->SetDataContext(&DataContext);

    HANDLE hThread1;

    hThread1=CreateThread(NULL,0,Thread2,this,0,NULL);

    CloseHandle(hThread1);

    return hr;

} // OnLoaded

DWORD WINAPI Thread2 (PVOID pArg)

{   

    HRESULT hr = E_NOTIMPL;

    MainPage* pMainPage = (MainPage *)pArg;

    while(i<2000)   

    {

        ++i;

            Sleep(200);

    pMainPage->UpdateData();

        }

    return 0;

}

HRESULT MainPage::UpdateData() 

{ 

    xrvalueNew.SetValue(i); 

       XRAutoCriticalSection csObject; 

       EnterCriticalSection(&csObject); 

       //pItemValue->SetValue(L"ID",&xrvalueNew);

       pDataValue->m_L1=i;

       m_pListBoxItem2->SetContent(&xrvalueNew);

       LeaveCriticalSection(&csObject);

              return S_OK; 

}

#pragma region GeneratedCode

// ============================================================================

//  WARNING: DO NOT EDIT THIS ALWAYS-GENERATED CODE

// ============================================================================

HRESULT MainPage::InitializeComponent()

{

    HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;

    FindName(L"LayoutRoot", &m_pLayoutRoot);

    FindName(L"Button1", &m_pButton1);

    FindName(L"ListBoxItem1", &m_pListBoxItem1);

    FindName(L"ListBoxItem2", &m_pListBoxItem2);

    if (m_pLayoutRoot &&

        m_pButton1 &&

        m_pListBoxItem1 &&

        m_pListBoxItem2

       )

    {

        hr = S_OK;

    }

    return hr;

}

// ============================================================================

//  WARNING: DO NOT EDIT THIS ALWAYS-GENERATED CODE

// ============================================================================

#pragma endregion GeneratedCode
```

the result like that:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/nl-BE/winembnatapp/thread/52e0fd82-e81b-448f-a518-1a8bef5dd8e4

What is the exact way  if I want to use DataBinding?I want to build a HMI ,It maybe has hundreds of value and in per 500ms maybe refresh  dozens item.

Is SetContent() a feasible way can use in a production environment?

Comment: that loop with the sleep() in looks a bit unpleasant....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the TPropertyBag directly. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh336382.aspx)

```
// Don't do this
//pDataValue->m_L1=i;

// Do this instead
pDataValue->SetValue(L"L1", &i)
```

Comment: I tried this,pDataValue->SetValue(L"L1",&xrvalueNew);but the problem is same.

Comment: Everything else looks OK. There are a couple of things that I'm a little doubtful on: 1) ListBoxItem is usually used inside a ListBox. I don't know if there are virtualization tricks that is involved. Try a TextBox instead. 2) The value is being changed on a thread that is not the main thread. This means the event handler is not on the main thread either. Perhaps one of these techniques here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783713/c-win32-executing-a-method-on-ui-thread-due-to-an-event-on-background-thread

Comment: I read this article and others about MESSAGE MAP, but Silverlight for Windows Embedded can not supply MFC, and it based a modal dialog box,so seems not have a MESSAGE LOOP. Then I searth a article http://www.phytec.com/pdf/application_notes/Silverlight_LAN-053.pdf ,it use a timer based Storyboard,then the UI thread get the value instead the data thread push. I don't know is it a best idea. Thank you very very much!!

Comment: According to this document, there is a message loop http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee502510(v=winembedded.60).aspx

Comment: Oh，this information from you is very helpful. I tried it that can run as well. May I ask you another question? If my program has another thread, then I have two threads without window, how can the threads communication like message loop?not like WaitForSingleObject makes the thread block. Thank you very much indeed for your help!

Comment: There is not one right answer. Some people use a hidden window. Otherwise, you can create your own queue-like data structure.