# Asynchronous Procedure Calls

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, winapi, asynchronous

I'm trying to get [APC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681951%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to work in my C++ code but I fail. I'm lost for words. In C# it works all fine (logically the same code). I want thread 2 to inject a call into thread 1. But in my C++ project it wont execute for some reason. What am I doing wrong ?

- thread 1 (main thread)
- thread 2 (sub thread, that needs the main thread to execute a function)

---

**Code:**

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "windows.h"

#define TIME 2500
#define LAST_ERROR printf("last error: %i\r\n", GetLastError());

HANDLE handle1, handle2;

void ThreadInfo(char* prefix = "")
{
    printf("%sthread id: %i\r\n", prefix, GetCurrentThreadId());
}

VOID CALLBACK apc( _In_ ULONG_PTR data)
{
    ThreadInfo(" -> apc: 2 -> 1: ");
}

void run1()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Sleep(TIME);
        ThreadInfo("1: ");

        // apc
        //QueueUserAPC(apc, handle2, (ULONG_PTR) NULL);
    }
}

void run2()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Sleep(TIME);
        ThreadInfo("2: ");

        // apc
        QueueUserAPC(apc, handle1, (ULONG_PTR) NULL);
    }
}

void TestThreads()
{
    DWORD threadId;
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES a;
    a.nLength = 12;
    a.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    a.bInheritHandle = 1;

    DuplicateHandle(GetCurrentProcess(), GetCurrentThread(), GetCurrentProcess(), &handle1, 0, true, 2);
    LAST_ERROR

    handle2 = CreateThread(NULL, 100000, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)run2, NULL, 0, &threadId);
    printf("handles (1, 2): %i, %i\r\n", handle1, handle2);
    printf("ids (1, 2): %i, %i\r\n", threadId, GetCurrentThreadId());
    printf("--------------------------------\r\n");
    run1();
}

int main()
{
    TestThreads();

    printf("done.");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
  Sleep(TIME);
```

That's your problem statement.  APCs are pretty dangerous, they permit code re-entrancy.  The rough equivalent to the infamous Application.DoEvents() statement that got so many VB programmers in trouble.  Windows doesn't just let them run, you have to be *explicit* that your code is re-entrant so that the APC can safely run without screwing up your program state.

The specific requirement is that your thread is in an "alertable wait state".  Getting into a wait state is not the issue, the Sleep() call does that.  It is however not an alertable state.  You have to use this instead:

```
  SleepEx(TIME, TRUE);
```

Modify the run1() function in your test program and you'll now see the APC callback getting called.  Compare to GetOverlappedResultEx(), SignalObjectAndWait(), WaitForSingleObjectEx() and WaitForMultipleObjectsEx(), other winapi calls that can put a thread in an alertable wait state.  And yes, Thread.Sleep() in a managed program is alertable, the CLR calls SleepEx() under the hood.

Comment: Where have you been hours ago ? :) I would have **never** guessed it to be the unimposing `Sleep`.

Comment: I was asleepex :)  My compliments on your repro code, wish that every SO user would make it as easy to help them as you did.

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3783845/1442225) there would be no way to make a _healthy_ GUI thread to accept APC calls itself, right ? I have to use this in MFC now.

Comment: No, blocking the UI thread only produces a dead user interface.