# Windows Messages

Tags: c#, winapi

I need send a custom windows message with a custom Id that another application will listen for.

Is there any predefined range of message Id ' s that Windows reserve for internal messages, such as SQL Server does (up to 50.000 for Internal messages)?

Comment: Documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/293723/how-could-i-create-a-custom-windows-message

Comment: @CodeCaster That's not a great duplicate. That question seems to talk about messages within a single process. RegisterWindowsMessage would seem to be the way forward here.

Comment: Hi @DavidHeffernan! 

Yes, I was looking for RegisterWindowsMessage. I found it with the link that you posted. Thank you!.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927.aspx) says:

> **Application-Defined Messages**
>
> An application can create messages to be used by its own windows or to communicate with windows in other processes. If an application creates its own messages, the window procedure that receives them must interpret the messages and provide appropriate processing.
>
> Message-identifier values are used as follows:
>
> - The system reserves message-identifier values in the range 0x0000 through 0x03FF (the value of [**WM_USER**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644931.aspx) – 1) for system-defined messages. Applications cannot use these values for private messages.
> - Values in the range 0x0400 (the value of [**WM_USER**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644931.aspx)) through 0x7FFF are available for message identifiers for private window classes.
> - If your application is marked version 4.0, you can use message-identifier values in the range 0x8000 ([**WM_APP**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644930.aspx)) through 0xBFFF for private messages.
> - The system returns a message identifier in the range 0xC000 through 0xFFFF when an application calls the [**RegisterWindowMessage**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644947.aspx) function to register a message. The message identifier returned by this function is guaranteed to be unique throughout the system. Use of this function prevents conflicts that can arise if other applications use the same message identifier for different purposes.

I suspect that `RegisterWindowMessage` is the right choice for you.