# Update UI of other project in 1 solution

Tags: wpf, vb.net

Is it possible to update the UI of Project1 using Project2 in the same solution? I managed to run and access the classes in Project1 using Project2 but not the controls. So far I tried the ff:

In Project1 `Loaded()` event:

```
    Dim newMenu As MenuItem
    newMenu = New MenuItem()
    newMenu.Header = "This is new"
    newMenu.Tag = "1"
    AddHandler newMenu.Click, New EventHandler(AddressOf menuClick)
    myMenu.Items.Add(newMenu)
```

In `menuClick()`,

```
Private Sub menuClick(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    If sender.Tag = "1" Then
        Dim progTag As Integer = Integer.Parse(sender.Tag)
        Dim restriction = (From x In localdb.Restrictions
                           Where x.Username = "oliverc" Where x.Program_ID = progTag
                           Select x.Module_ID)

        If restriction.Count > 0 Then
            For Each ListItem In restriction.ToList
                restrict.Add(New Project2.Restrictions() With {.RestrictionTag = ListItem.ToString})
            Next
        End If

        For Each ListItem In restrict
            MessageBox.Show(ListItem.RestrictionTag(0))
        Next



        Dim frm As Project2.MainWindow = New Project2.MainWindow()
        frm.ShowDialog()

    End If
End Sub
```

In Project2 `Loaded()`,

```
 For Each ListItem In listOfRestriction
        Select Case ListItem.ToString
            Case "1"
                btn_addRegion.IsEnabled = False
        End Select
        MessageBox.Show(ListItem.ToString)
    Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: **No.**

Long answer:

Each project will be compiled to a standalone .exe or .dll. Even if the current way you're trying to do it would be possible, the `Project2`-exe cannot possibly know which instance (if there is any at the time) of `Project1` it should modify.

In order to communicate at all with the other exe you need to implement [**Interprocess communication**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx). Then you'd have to have `Project1` ***change itself*** whenever it is told to do so by `Project2`.

Some types of IPC you can use:

- [**Anonymous or Named pipes**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762927(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [**Memory Mapped Files**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [**TCP communication**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c19ex43h(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [**Window Messages**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293723/how-could-i-create-a-custom-windows-message)